# How to create a restart button in wx.Python - Python

Tags: python, wxpython

So I have a program that opens up and does stuff.. However, is there a way to either restart the frame that is open or is there a way to close and open the frame again without have to rerun the program?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

- `frame.Iconize()` to minimize your window
- Hide it using methods:

  ```
  window.Hide()

  window.Show(n) with n= True or False
  ```

With the second alternative the frame disappears, so you need some method to call your frame back (maybe leaving visible a small parent or child frame with a button to call the hidden frame).
**Edit**: As @Fenikso indicates below, the best way to get back your hidden window is using `wx.TaskBarIcon`. You have an example in the comments below.

Comment: Tray icon is also great way how to access hidden frame.

Comment: @Fenikso, I'm not sure which icon do you refer to. After Hide() the application disappears from the taskbar. Even it disappears from the list of active tasks in the windows task administrator.

Comment: I mean tray icon, next to the clock on Windows. And of course you have to make one for you app using `wx.TaskBarIcon`.

Comment: @Fenikso. Great!, I was not aware of that widget. You should post it as an answer... [Here](http://mayankjohri.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/demo-code-for-wx-taskbaricon/) there is a complete example.